# How to restore state if user relaunches app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

right now I have an app with a couple of pages in which the user uses a ListPicker to select certain values, which are saved into public string variables. When the user reaches the last page, several textblock controls read the string variables and display the string. Along with this, a timer is shown that starts counting when the user reached this last page.

Now, if the user leaves the app by pressing the home button and then uses the app switcher to go back to it, the last page shows up without a hitch, all textblocks showing their variables and the timer hasn't stopped. However, if the user relaunches the app from the home screen instead of switching to it, all variables are lost and the app starts on the first page.

What I want to do is save the string variables and the timer, and have the app load the variables on startup if != null. If they exist, and the app is able to load them, navigate to the last page and show them. Otherwise, if there are no variables to load, simply continue normal operations.

How can I go about doing this? I've read about isolated storage and saving states, but quite honestly, haven't been able to accomplish anything, and it's really driving me crazy.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the app target 7.1 or 8.0?

Answer (score 0):

You should be implementing fast app resume. 
First,  you need to set the ActivationPolicy="Resume" in WMAppManifest.xml

Next
Go into App.xaml.cs in the "App" class add:
    private bool reset
You should then have a method for InitializePhoneApplication that initializes the RootFrame. Add this:

```
RootFrame.Navigating += RootFrame_Navigating;
RootFrame.Navigated += RootFrame_Navigated;
```

Then you can go and add those methods:

```
void RootFrame_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
        if (reset && e.IsCancelable && e.Uri.OriginalString == "/MainPage.xaml")
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        reset = false;
    }
}

void RootFrame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    reset = e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Reset;
}
```

If you implement this properly, your app should resume from the last page you were on.